# Adding component in cakephp 2.3.4

Tags: cakephp-2.3

How to add a component with check first if the component is exist. 
I used this on cakephp 2.2.3

```
public function __construct( $request = null, $response = null ) {
    parent::__construct( $request, $response );
    $this->_setupApplicationComponents();
}

protected function _setupApplicationComponents() {
if ( App::import( 'Component', 'Search.Prg' ) ) {
    $this->components[] = 'Search.Prg';
}
}
```

it not work on cakephp 2.3.4.
Anyone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you would check if a component exists before using it; CakePHP will automatically produce errors if a component could not be found?

CakePHP 2.3 uses 'lazy loading', which means that the component is not actually loaded/constructed until it is actually used. This means a lot less overhead, and will make your application work faster.

To **indicate** that you may use a certain class (component), use `App::uses()`; See [**Loading Classes**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-classes)

In your situation, to load the `Prg` component from the `Search` Plugin;

```
App::uses('Prg', 'Search.Controller/Component');
```

However, to use a component, just add it to the `$components` array of your Controller, and CakePHP should handle it automatically;

```
public $components = array(
    // Pluginname.Componentname
    'Search.Prg',
);
```

See [**Using Components**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#using-components)

Comment: Actually components are not lazy loaded, only models (at least on 2.6.3). Every component you place in `$components` gets initialized.